# css nth-child selector doesn't work with styled mui component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a styled component like this:

```
const FormBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: "47vw",
  height: "25vh",
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100],
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  marginLeft: "auto",
  marginRight: "auto",
  marginTop: theme.spacing(5),
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "space-between",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
  columnGap: theme.spacing(5),
  "&>*": { flex: "0 1 auto" },
  "&:nth-child(4)": { flex: "1 1 200px", backgroundColor: "red" }, //????????????? 
}));
```

in the last line of code I targeted the 4th child(the button component in the bellow code) and I want to apply some CSS on it but it doesn't work.

and inside this styled component there are four child as bellow:

```
<FormBox component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField label="Title">{title}</TextField>
      <TextField label="Amount">{amount}</TextField>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePicker
          label="Date"
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setDate(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
          sx={{ width: 50 }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
      <Button variant="contained" sx={{height: 50}}>Add</Button>
    </FormBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with `&>*:nth-child(4)` instead of `&:nth-child(4)`.

You can make sense from this link.
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/css+selector+last+element

Comment: Some explanation of that syntax or a link to a related resource would make this a better answer.

Comment: Hmm, it worked but I don't know the reason. if you add some explanation it would be nice. anyway, appreciate it.

Comment: I have just added reference link

Comment: @RichardWang, please don't include codegrepper links. In addition to almost being a spam site, their snippets change all the time, so it is like just posting a link to Google.

Answer (score 3):

The `&` is a special selector invented by SCSS which is used in nested selectors to refer to the outer selector.

So the following code represents select the fourth `FormBox` element.

```
FormBox = {
  "&:nth-child(4)": { // your style here },
}
```

If you want to select the fourth child element, please select all child elements of `FormBox` with `>*` first, then try to select the fourth child with `:nth-child(4)`.

```
FormBox = {
  "&>*:nth-child(4)": { // your style here },
}
```

By the way, `&>:nth-child(4)` can achieve the same effect.

> The asterisk is optional with simple selectors. For instance, *.warning and .warning are equivalent.[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

The following two links have more examples and may help you:

[MDN/CSS_Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

[w3schools/css_selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)